# grab a text then submit that text to a specific route

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do is grab a text then submit that text to a specific route of application where form input name="mykeyword" is accepted and i also want this open in new tab in browser.

I did some practice but no luck. Any idea?

```js
    $("#ScanTitle").click(function () {
                var mykeyword = $("#mykeyword").text();
                // the 'mykeyword' variable will be submitted to 'Search/Index' route with INPUT name='mykeyword' form attribute in new window
                $.post('Search/Index', function (data) {
                
                var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
                w.document.write(data);
                w.document.close();
                });
            
            });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    
        <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <button id="ScanTitle">button</button>
    <p id="mykeyword">hand bags</p>
    
   
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think there are errors in your code, but I am not sure if your **$.post** is working, and also it seems you are not posting any data. can you press **F12** and view if there is any error msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the parameter to `$.post`:

```
$.post('Search/Index', {name: myKeyword}, function(data) {
    var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
});
```

To get around the popup blocker, you need to open the window in the click handler, not the AJAX callback.

```
$("#ScanTitle").click(function() {
  var mykeyword = $("#mykeyword").text();
  var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
  $.post('Search/Index', {name: myKeyword}, function(data) {
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't open new window with post

Comment: Turn off your popup blocker and it will. The popup blocker prevents opening a new window if it's not inside a user-initialted event handler. Since it's happening in the AJAX callback, the browser loses the connection with the click event.