# JavaScript post request like open new window popup blocker

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a script post request data and open new page.

Do you know how to open it just as a new tab or new window? I don't want to set the target as _blank as I want people to have my site open as well.

How to block popup open new window.

**Script**

```
function printPDF(task) {
  var fdata = {
    "record": "'.$this->bean->id.'"
  };
  //  var params = jQuery.param(fdata);
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: fdata,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "index.php?module=ginvo_client_invoice&action=printinvoice",
    error: function(resp) {},
    success: function(resp) {
      var invoicedetails = JSON.stringify(resp);
      //  console.log(resp);
      var param = {
        result: invoicedetails
      };
      post("custom/clientinvoice.php", param);
    }
  });

  function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    for (var key in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        var inputField = document.createElement("input");
        inputField.type = "hidden";
        inputField.name = key;
        inputField.value = params[key];
        form.appendChild(inputField);
      }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    window.open(path, "_blank");
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting a dialog box on your page. See jQuery dialog window for some ideas: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009344/grab-a-text-then-submit-that-text-to-a-specific-route/46009425#46009425) for how to fill in a popup window in an ajax callback.